Is the source code of https://vscode.dev open source?
By cloning the code on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode, use ./scripts/code-web.bat, I can build a browser version of VS Code, but it is not the same as the code on https://vscode.dev.

Is the source code of https://vscode.dev open source?
Can I build the same code as that site?
I looked at the package.json file source code of VS Code and didn't find any build command that can build the same as https://vscode.dev.

at a quick glance, seems just like a difference in settings and installed extensions (remote dev)
